# Neo4J online backup — any way to address the security flaw?

Tags: neo4j

If I am to make an online backup using the neo4j-admin backup tool remotely, as is [advised by Neo4J](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/4.0/backup/), I have to open a public IP and the backup port on my Neo4J application.

However, I don't see neo4j-admin asking for any login credentials, basically making it possible for anybody to access the server and copy all the data while the port is opened.

There is no setting inside the neo4j.conf that would only accept backup requests from a certain address.

So what does it mean? When the online backups are done remotely, as is advised, the database may be vulnerable to somebody else just copying all the data.

I didn't find anything in Neo4J documentation that addresses this flaw (only a warning) and it looks like in more than 7 years that this feature has been available as a part of the commercial enterprise version there has not been any solution offered for this.

What do you do to protect the DB then? At the moment the only solution seems to not back it up remotely, but that causes additional stress on the server and is not the best solution. Plus the online backup is not stable when done locally for large DBs. Another solution could be to only open the port remotely via some kind of API to the server, but that may still be exploited if somebody figures out the time frame when the backup is made.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states that ne04j-admin must be invoked as the neo4j user. That is the user that owns the neo4j executables and the databases. So the security is handled by the OS login and the file permissions should be set to prevent unathorised access to the neo4j directories/files including the neo4j-admin executable.